# What does a simple passive circuit to simulate an impedance mismatch look like?

Tags: passive-networks, impedance-matching, passive-filter, input-impedance

I am trying to learn some of the basics of circuit design. One thing I am curious to make a filter/schematic of is what happens when a voltage source hits an impedance mismatch.

eg. A high impedance audio signal (like a passive electric guitar output around 7,000 to 15,000 Ohms) hitting a low impedance input (like a mixing desk at 2,000 to 5,000 Ohms).

What would a circuit like that look like so I can simulate it to see how the mismatch affects the output or frequency spectrum?

Also, if it is purely an impedance mismatch will the frequency response be flat across (ie. just a gain response)? Does there need to be capacitance/inductance involved in the simulation for there to be a low pass effect to it? How might that typically present?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually in audio circuits, the signal is in the form of a  "voltage". So we do not care about the impedance matching.  And we usually want R_source << R_Load. Because only when R_source << R_Load all the voltage generated by a signal source is present across the load resistance (Voltage divider circuit).

Comment: To add to @G36: An electric guitar pickup is (or was) a variable reluctance device. These do NOT only have a source resistance. They actually have a source impedance. Similarly, I suspect that the mixing desk inputs also have an impedance that is unlikely to be a simple resistance.  So the equation expressing the impact of hooking up the two, while relatively simple in principle, isn't entirely simple to present. Your frequency response question matters. The behavior is very likely also frequency dependent. There may be different delays or different gains,etc. What level of answer do you want?

Comment: I'm wondering primarily just: (1) If it is solely a pure theoretical impedance mismatch only, will it simply result in a gain reduction effect? If so, what would this look like as a circuit given a source impedance and input impedance? (2) Secondly, say there was a basic low pass filter effect - what would a simple way to modify the pure impedance mismatch circuit to implement that as well? I am looking for the simplest theoretical way to conceptualize these questions as a circuit.

Comment: You are using the term "impedance mismatch" incorrectly.  Impedance matching is generally only important at high frequencies to avoid reflections and sometimes for maximum power transfer.  What you have is a source with an  impedance and a load with an impedance. There is no need for matching these impedances (as already pointed out, you will lose signal if you make the load impedance equal to the source impedance).  Usually you choose the load impedance fto meet one or more of several goals: maximize the signal level, minimize noise, minimize the effect of external signals coupling in, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging a passive electric guitar to a low impedance input will generally not yield satisfactory results. Check my answer here about loading passive pickups: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/566375/237061 in short: its resonance will be damped and signal will be weak as others have said.

While impedance matching is usually a term used in high frequency signal and power transmission, I've seen the term also in the context you describe, but I consider it a misnomer.

What people do is lower the source impedance as much as possible e.g. by a preamp before giving it to a low impedance input such as a mixing desk. They don't try to match the input impedance. Some mixing desks also have dedicated instrument inputs which have a high input impedance. Although this will not load the pickups resistively, you still have the cable capacitance which will load the pickup and change its resonant behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you could build an L-pad, this will attenuate the signal, but also provide an increased impedance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZisMx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Read Barry’s comment. An impedance mismatch will effect frequency response only when the wave nature of electricity is important...so only when wires have to be thought of as transmission lines.  (This means only when the length of the wires are a large fraction of a wavelength.) For your case, an impedance mismatch would be important if the guitar pickup cable was many 100’s or 1000’s of feet long.  For normal lengths, you will not see any transmission line effects, and so “impedance mismatches” are just resistive voltage dividers, and pickup cables can be modeled as their wire to shield capacitance ( which, of course, will effect frequency response as every lumped capacitance does.)